# How to merge citations from two different google scholar accounts?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

I have two gmail accounts. Each has its own Scholar account. I want to merge them both so that my citations are unified. As I have different citations on both accounts.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no direct way. You could choose the account with the most citations and then manually cite the other publications from the account with less citations.

Also, you could try to export the citations from the smaller account to your hard drive and deactivate that account. Then rebuild the other scholar account over time.

A person over [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/I_have_two_google_scholar_accounts_personal_mail_and_uni_how_can_I_merge_them) asked the same question but there was no definitive answer.

Comment: I can attest to the lack of ready solutions to this. I had the same issue just six months ago. As @Nour suggests, I resorted to manual citation entry.