# Making one of two Google Scholar accounts default with given email address

Tags: publications, google-scholar

I had a Google Scholar account with my full name with only 3 citations. Later I created another account with abbreviated name but same email address. Email was verified and most of my citations are here. Today I got an email to verify email of the old account and I did it. After that the old account has become my default with my email address. I want to make my other account with most citations default. Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Comment: You should contact google, maybe they can merge the accounts.

Comment: What do you mean by "default"?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that "Email was verified" refers to the verified academic email address and not the GMail address associated with your account, since that is the only extra verification step asked by Google Scholar that I know of. Then, the following should likely work:

1. Log in to the old account, and click on the pencil icon near your profile photo to edit your profile. There, remove the email address from the "Email for verification" field and save.
2. Log out and log in to the new account, add the email in the same field by editing your profile, and save. This would probably send you a verification email again, which you would need to confirm.

Further, if you wish to (imperfectly) [combine both accounts](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/115278/68109), it should be possible to delete the old account in the settings, and add those articles to your new account using the "Add articles" option, but I am not entirely sure if the citations will get handled correctly.